# How to write a shell script that runs next command even if current command fails?

Tags: linux, shell

I currently need to automate a task where I need to execute 5 commands, even if any command fails, all next commands should get executed, currently if 4th commands fails, shell script exits and dont run 5th command.

So, what should I do so that, shell script run all the next commands even if current command fails?

Comment: Post you shell script here, please (the relevant part). It shouldn't exit without special instructions to exit on failure. Maybe you use make?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that you have bash as your script interpreter
(or /bin/sh is a symbolic link to bash),
please check if your script does not have

```
set -e
```

anywhere in the code.

Answer (score 4):

Well, what's wrong with code below?

```
#!/bin/bash
cmd1
cmd2
cmd3
cmd4
cmd5
```

Answer (score 4):

I would do

```
|| true
```

Example:

```
( set -e; false ; echo not here; )
( set -e; false || true ; echo still here; )
```

Example:

```
command1 || true
command2 || true
command3 || true
command4 || true
command5 || true
```

That way you can keep the -e flag, its a good flag.

Answer (score 1):

The "trap" command may be helpful here:

[trap](http://linuxcommand.org/wss0160.php)